# Downloaded echo sign signed document is password protected, How to download it without password

Tags: c#, passwords, document, signed, echosign

I am trying to download the signed document from EchoSign using my c#.
Api Method: GET /agreements/{agreementId}/combinedDocument

I am able to get the file stream in response but after saving it my local drive when I am trying to open the saved PDF it is prompting for Password.
I am using below c# code to save the file stream to my local drive

```
string stream = adobeObject.DownloadAgreementDocument(agreementId);
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stream);
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\Agreement.pdf", bytes);
```

I am not sure why it is protected.

Answer (score 0):

What you do is first you have to go back to the main page (AKA Login page), and click; "Forgot Password." They should email you another password if you can answer you security question! Only if you have one tho'

Comment: The password is for the PDF, not for the site (unless it encrypts to the user's password, but that would require the site password in plaintext, which is generally bad)